# Android: How do I compare ImageSpan drawable to XML resource drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, emoji, imagespan

I have a question which I cannot find an answer for too long and I would appreciate if you can help.

I have a TextEdit which I add icons (Emojis) into it between the text.
The Icons are stored in an ImageSpan[] array named imagesInTxt.
Then I loop through the ImageSpan[] and I am trying to compare its drawable or whatever constant value that it can offer to the resource from the XML, Eg: R.Drawable.Smiley that was used as icons in the first place.

The problem is that the unique identifier that returns from getResources().getDrawable(R.Drawable.smiley) does not match the identifier than I get from imagesInTxt[x].getDrawable(), although we are talking about the same icon exactly.

I don't want and don't see a way to use .SetTag() and .GetTag() because I am dealing with ImageSpan[] from within the EditText and not the button itself, so this solution is not helping me.

I don't want to compare the ImageSpan[] directly to the ImageView button. I need to compare it to the original resource that I used (Eg: R.Drawable.xxxx) in any way possible.

How can I achieve that ? 
If it is impossible, what can you suggest as an alternative solution ?

```
ImageSpan[] imagesInTxt = txt.getSpans(0, txt.length(), ImageSpan.class);

for (int x = 0; x < itemSpans.length; x++) { // Go through the ICONS

        Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.Drawable.smiley);            

            if(imagesInTxt[x].getDrawable().equals(myIcon)) {               
                Icon = ";-)";
            }

myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sad);

if(imagesInTxt[x].getDrawable().equals(myIcon)) {               
                Icon = ";-(";
            }

}
```

Comment: use `Drawable.ConstantState getConstantState()`

Comment: I tried using getConstantState(). didn't help. I still get different identifiers when comparing between the ImageSpan[x] and getResources().getDrawable(R.Drawable.smiley). Mainly when leaving the application and reopening it. I need something that will be constant in the code and that will survive closing and reopening of the application of course, or else it will not enter the if condition again.

Comment: then create a custom `ImageSpan` class